# Simple exp:channel:entries not working on specific template

Tags: templates, channel, tags

I have a very simple exp:channel:entries tag that works on several template files but not on the specific one I want to use it on. I am new to Expressionengine, but from everything I know about it, what data you can should not depend on context. But that is how this is acting sort of. I have also tested to see if it is some error in the template file by deleting everything but this tag and it still does not work in this location. Can anyone please explain why this tag would not work in this specific template? Thanks all for the help.

```
{exp:channel:entries
channel="insights"
disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
limit="2"
} {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "not working"? Also, please provide the URL structure of the location where this is happening.

Comment: try with dynamic="no" in the exp:channel:entries tag

Comment: You do have /something/ between the open and close tags right?  Like {title} at least, right?

Comment: adding dynamic="no" worked great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Adding dynamic="no" fixed this issue.

Comment: You are welcome, can you change the status in Resolved

Comment: David, thanks for re-posting as an answer. You can accept your own answer to show that this question has been answered. See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [Can I answer my own question?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)